# delphi dbgrid boolean value, accept f fa fal fals false , how to accept more values?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2009

I'm using mssql and Delphi 2009.
When a form contains a dbgrid that is connected to boolean field, the values are displayed as `True`, or `False`.
The Delphi dbgrid has the ability to translate

```
f
fa
fal
fals
false
t
tr
tru
true
```

to be `true` or `false`. 
I want to add values so it can accept other strings, and match them to `true` or `false`.
Where could these values be added?

Comment: What method do you use to verify the dbgrid translates those? What I doubt is it may not be translation at all. If you're entering text for instance, it just may be auto completing to sTextFalse/sTextTrue.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz that is my question. i dont know how the Delphi does it, and I'm looking for the method that check the f to make it false. i really doubt its in the sql.

Comment: @none - Your question is how to modify possible true/false entry possibilities. My question is how have you concluded that the dbgrid translates fa to false.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz test it with small simple application , that has a dbgrid and an adoquery connected to mssql table, containing boolean field, to that field change from true to fal. and see the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the default behavior for [`TBooleanField.DisplayValues`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TBooleanField_DisplayValues.html). Look at the `db` unit source:
`db.TBooleanField.SetAsString` and `db.TBooleanField.SetDisplayValues`.

If you set `TField.DisplayValues := 'Yes;No';` for example: `Y`, `Ye`, `Yes` will represent `True`; `N`, `No` will represent `False`.

You cannot add more values to it. Unless you utilize `OnSetText` as suggested by the other answer, or use a `TDbGrid.PickList`.

Personally, I would use a `CheckBox` for Boolean field value representation on the `TDBGrid`.
There are plenty of [examples](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa082003a.htm) out there on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an `OnSetText` event for your boolean field, and interpret any given text as `True` or `False`.